# sphinx rest wrong enumerated list alignment

Tags: python-sphinx

I wrote a documentation for a TP using sphinx-ReST. I have some difficulties to get a proper alignment of enumerated list. As you can see on the page below, if I add a `code-block` directive inside an enumerated list, the alignment is wrong.

http://gvallver.perso.univ-pau.fr/vasptp/part_3_NiO.html

See source code on the left for the entire source code of the page. Hereafter is a short example :

```
normal text .... bla bla

    1. question 1

        1.a sub question 1

        1.b sub question 2

.. code-block:: console

    mkdir toto

..

        1.c sub question 3
```

If you use the above code the question 1.c is not aligned with question 1.a and 1.b, see below.

[image]

Comment: How about moving the code-block to the right so that it aligns with sub question 2?

Comment: Yes it works. Nevertheless, if I look at the html code, enumerate list are not always recognized and written as `<ol>`, particularly in the case of long text.